# Xamarin.forms ios MonoTouchException on Navigation.RemovePage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

In my xamarin.forms ios application I have 4 ContentPages and 1 Popup(Rg.Plugin)

My Navigation is like this

Page 1--> Page 2 --> Page 3 --> Page 4 --> Popup

I want to navigate to Page 1 from a button click in Popup by removing the pages(2,3,4 and Popup).

I done it like this.

```
  private  void OK_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var countPagesToRemove = 3;
                var mainPage = (Application.Current.MainPage as NavigationPage);
                for (var i = 1; i < countPagesToRemove; i++)
                {

                    mainPage.Navigation.RemovePage(mainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack[mainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 2]);
                }
                 Navigation.PopAsync();
                 Task.Delay(5);
                 PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                 DisplayAlert("Result", ex.Message, "ok");
            }
        }
```

This works perfectly on Android.In ios it throws me this exception.

```
Foundation.MonoTouchException
  Message=Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: CALayerInvalidGeometry Reason: CALayer bounds contains NaN: [0 0; 0 nan]
Native stack trace:

  Source=Xamarin.iOS
  StackTrace:
  at ObjCRuntime.Runtime.ThrowNSException (System.IntPtr ns_exception) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.14.1.39/src/Xamarin.iOS/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:406 
  at ObjCRuntime.Runtime.throw_ns_exception (System.IntPtr exc) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/runtime/Delegates.generated.cs:128 
  at (wrapper native-to-managed) ObjCRuntime.Runtime.throw_ns_exception(intptr)
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.14.1.39/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:86 
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0000e] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.14.1.39/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:65
```

I have no idea what does this mean. I have searched and many people got this issues in several situations.But I didn't something like my scenerio.How to solve this?Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If page 1 is the Root Page , invoke the line `await Navigation.PopToRootAsync();` directly .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Hi lucas. Sorry for not mentioning, I have a landing page before page 1. But I want to navigate to page 1

Comment: Could you share your sample so that I can test it on my side ?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Ok. I will give my sample repo

Comment: Hi,any update ?

Comment: Hi bro. When I try a sample repo.It works . So its was something else. A resource file was missing. Thanks for suggesting to create a sample repo.It isolated the problem

Comment: You could share the answer and accept it :)